# Programmatically add bundle products to cart Magento

Tags: php, magento, cart, product

So I've got a bundle product, that contains 6 products. I've written code to add this bundle to the cart, programmatically adding all 6 options to the bundle... But I get this `Call to a member function getPosition() on a non-object` error... It happens in the `shakeSelections` function, but it doesn't make sense because all the objects and stuff needs to go, like the `$a`and `$b` need to be of a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` data type and they are, its just the getOption method does not exist within it... Is there something i'm doing wrong?

This is my custom addAction in my custom controller:

```
public function addAction() {
        $prdId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();

        $_return = array('code' => 0, 'message' => 'Something went wrong...');

        if (!empty($prdId)) {
            $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
            $product->load($prdId);

            if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);
                $optionCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsCollection($product);

                $selectionCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection(
                    $typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product),
                    $product
                    );

                $this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false,
                    Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck()
                    );

                $bundle_option = array();

                foreach ($this->_options as $key => $value) {
                    foreach ($value['selections'] as $selKey => $selection) {
                        $bundle_option[$selection->option_id][] = $selection['selection_id'];
                    }
                }

                $params = array(
                    'product' => $prdId,
                    'related_product' => '',
                    'bundle_option' => $bundle_option,
                    'qty' => '1',
                );

                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $cart->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

The url is basically: `/forty/cart/add/product/11` Where 11 is the id of the bundled product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here some modification in your code should be work

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);

if($product->getTypeId() == "bundle"){

    $bundled_items = array();
    $optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();
    $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
    $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);

    foreach($options as $option) {
        $_selections = $option->getSelections();

        foreach($_selections as $selection) {
            $bundled_items[$option->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
    }

    $params = array('bundle_option' => $bundled_items,'qty' => 1,'product'=>$productId);
}

if (isset($params['qty'])) {
    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
        array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
        );
    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
}

$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load($productId);

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();

Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
    array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
);
```

Hope this will sure work for you.

Let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, got me further! I edited your response with your code working with mine.. Couple of bugs here and there..

Comment: @MaraisRossouw, I am glad,i could give you correct way.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting `Selected required options are not available`